# How to insert into a table data and select from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I want to do something like this:

```
My tb_b:
---------------
   B   |   C     // Columns
---------------
  'y'  |  'z'    // row
---------------
```

EX: INSERT INTO tb_a(a,b,c) VALUES ('x',SELECT * from tb_b)

I want this result:

```
My tb_a:
-----------------
 A  |   B   |   C     // Columns
-----------------
'x' |  'y'  |  'z'    // row
-----------------
```

How to Insert into table a data and selected rows from tb_b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tb_a (a, b, c)
SELECT 'x', tb_b.B, tb_b.C FROM tb_b
```

Comment: What does a,b,c refer to in `tb_a (a, b, c)`? How to insert for 3 fields in tb_a when it only have two columns?Also does `SELECT 'x', tb_b.B, tb_b.C FROM tb_b` means select row x , values in columns B and C